# Windows virtualenv issue - bin created instead of Script

Tags: python, windows, cmd, windows-10, virtualenv

I tried to create a virtualenv with Windows 10 cmd, and I followed steps below.

```
C:\Users\pahkey> cd \
C:\> mkdir venvs
C:\> cd venvs
C:\venvs> python -m venv mysite
C:\venvs>cd C:\venvs\mysite\Scripts
```

Here, error happens, it says "system cannnot find the file specified".

So I check inside mysite, there was "bin" instead of "Scripts".

As I said, I use Windows, not Linux/Mac.

I tried below,

```
C:\venvs>cd C:\venvs\mysite\bin
C:\venvs\mysite\bin> activate
```

it says "'activate is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

These are my current conditions.
[mysite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yNPN.png)
[bin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwUgR.png)

Anyone knows about this problem please help me...

```
C:\Users\pahkey> cd \
C:\> mkdir venvs
C:\> cd venvs
C:\venvs> python -m venv mysite
C:\venvs>cd C:\venvs\mysite\Scripts
C:\venvs>cd C:\venvs\mysite\bin
C:\venvs\mysite\bin> activate
```

Comment: Just a sanity check, did you install Python distribution for Windows or Linux?

Comment: you don't cd into a virtual env, you activate it. `C:\venvs> python -m venv mysite`, then `cd mysite`, then `Scripts\activate`. Now your runtime environment is the python virtual environment. And then you run the equivalent `deactivate` to exit the virtual environment again.

Comment: I installed Anaconda. Is it better to try again with conda prompt?